# sqlite query - select data which prefers some value

Tags: sql, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create an sqlite query but I'm having some problems.

Let's say that table has three columns id, foreign-id and value.

I need to select all rows with distinct foreign_id with a given value, however that value may not exist for all different foreign_ids.
In which case a row where value is set to some fallback value must be selected (such row always exists) for that foreign_id.

I apologize for my english since I'm not native english speaker.

Here is an example:

Table:

```
id | foreign_id | value
------------------------
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 2
3  | 1          | 3
4  | 2          | 1
5  | 2          | 3
```

If desired value is 2 and fallback value is 1 then the query should return

```
id | foreign_id | value|
------------------------
2  | 1          | 2
4  | 2          | 1
```

It return row with id 1 because it has desired value 2 for foreign_id 1.
And it return row with id 4 because for foreign_id 2 a row with value of 2 does not exits, so it selects a row with fallback value of 1.

Hope that clears up my question a bit.

Comment: can you give us an small example table, a sudo query, and what results you would expect with that query

Comment: Post an example of your data, a given value, and the desired result.

Comment: Posted an example in my question.

Comment: I see what you are asking... let me think for a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I produced based on Seth's answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (foreign_id), value, id FROM testTable 
  WHERE value = 2
UNION SELECT DISTINCT (foreign_id), value, id FROM testTable
  WHERE value = 1 
  AND foreign_id NOT IN 
  ( 
    SELECT foreign_id 
    FROM testTable
    WHERE value = 2
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with a Union... something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (foreign_id), value
FROM TABLE 
WHERE value = 2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT (foreign_id), '1' as value
FROM TABLE 
WHERE foreign_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT (foreign_id), value
  FROM TABLE 
  WHERE value = 2
)
```

where everything that has a value 2 set value as `2` and everything else sets value as `1`

(I haven't tested this query, you might have to do some tweaking)

Comment: Your example result in a error. But the thinking behind was good and so I used it to forge a good solution. Thank you.